# check email id already exists with using yup validation wrrong url how change setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

i try to use formik form with yup validation to see if a email already exist in database (i have a nestjs back on the port 8000 and my react front on the port 3000) so i do this:

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string()
      .min(2, 'votre surnom doit contenir minimum 2 caractères')
      .max(30, '30 caractères maximum autorisés')
      .required('Veuillez renseigner un pseudo'),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email('Veuillez renseigner une adresse mail valide')
      .required('Ce champs est obligatoire.')
      .test(
        'email check',
        'email déjà utiliser',
        async (value) =>
          await fetch('http:localhost:8000/users/check_email', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email: value })
          }).then((res) => res.json())
      ),
```

but when i try to test the email validation i got this error in the console

POST http://localhost:3000/localhost:8000/users/check_email 404 (Not Found)

so how i can change the settings of yup or react to not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct the http protocol in your url from `http:localhost:8000/` to `http://localhost:8000` so that `http://localhost:3000` does not get added at the start of the url.

Comment: thanks i didn't see i was forgetting the 2 //. I see you suggest something but you delete it can you tell me more about your suggestion.

Comment: @Ganzo I deleted it because it was not related to the question, but if you're going to use an async function with await in it, it's better if you don't use a .then block in it. You should change it to something like const res = await fetch(...) ; const json = await res.json(); and then do whatever you need with json. const res = await fetch(...) is equivalent to fetch(...).then((res) => {...})